# want to additional dropdown menu with Jquery - cant make it work properly using clone()

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm new to coding so please be gently - here goes:
I'm having a bit of a problem and was hoping someone could help.

I have a dynamic drop down menu for people to choose subjects and I would like to repeat this selection drop down to allow people to add more subjects. I can clone #subjselect and prepend it to #another but then if they click 'Add another' it will insert 2 copies of the dropdown box (and increase exponentially from there). I'm pretty sure this is to do with the clone, but I can't work out how to just add one at a time. Here is the code:
HTML:

#### Primary  Subject

```
    <div class="select">
    <select id="subject">
    <option value="">Subject</option>
    <option value="math">Math</option>
    <option value="science">Science</option>
    <option value="languages">Languages</option>
    <option value="humanities">Humanities</option>
    <option value="econ">Economics/Finance</option>
    <option value="gmat">GMAT</option>
    <option value="sat">SAT</option>
    </select>

    <select id="topic">
    <option value="">Topic</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="another" onclick="Repeat(this)"></br>Add Another Subject</a>
```

JQuery:

```
function Repeat(obj){
    var currentDiv = $(obj).prev('div');
    var dropDown = currentDiv.find('select');
    dropDown.clone().prependTo('#another');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your html markup, I think it should be `prev('div')` rather then `parent('div')`. Since the link is outside the div `.select` here:

```
function Repeat(obj) {
    var currentDiv = $(obj).prev('div');
    var dropDown = currentDiv.find('select');
    dropDown.clone().prependTo('#another');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this was a massive pain!!

Comment: have another issue related to this - perhaps you could help with that too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499952/creating-a-dynamic-menu-with-ajax-and-jquery

Comment: I mean if you have tim :-)

Comment: For the starters, you haven't changed your code to the above yet, in the code you have there...

Comment: Also, since the dropdowns are dynamically added, you need to use [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead of using the simple **.change()**

Comment: but the first drop down is static - only the 'topics' dropdown is added dynamically